# How do I track with Google Analytics the success "Contact page" in Magento 1.7.0.2?

Tags: php, jquery, magento, google-analytics

**Hi everyone!**

I want to track the **succesfull sents** of Contact Us with **Google Analytics**  in Magento 1.7.0.2.

The contact us page is included on **app/design/frontend/default/YOUR-TEMPLATE-NAME/template/contacts/form.phtml**

In my case I want to tract the "**Contact Us**" but only **the succesfull sents**.

Where should I include the code of Google Analytics in order to track only
the Success messages shown after the visitor sends me his info ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In google analytics you can add a trigger when a specific url is reached. (Destination URL)

**For example**: If someone submits the contact form in magento it redirects to http://www.example.com/index.php/contacts/index/post/.

This is how the form action will look :

**So google analytics code will be added as it is in Admin >> System >> Configuration >> Design >> HTML Head >> Miscellaneous Scripts**

But you need to create a Goal in Google Analytics where Destination URL will be http://www.example.com/index.php/contacts/index/post/

Note: Please use your website URL instead of example.com; this is used just for reference.